# Issue using ckeditor 4.5.9 with php

Tags: php, ckeditor

been looking for and trying everything to get this to work but just cannot seem to get it to do so.

Had previous code from some years ago that included an older version of ckeditor. It works fine but wanted to get a newer version going on the site and downloaded the latest (4.5.9).

The older version included the files ckeditor_php4.php, ckeditor_php5.php and ckeditor.php while the newer version has the file ckeditor.js.

Using the sample code given I was able to get this to work with no issues as a straight HTML page but when trying to include it into my PHP code nothing displays?

```
<script src='lib/ckeditor-new/ckeditor.js'></script>

<form>
<textarea name='editor1' id='editor1' rows='10' cols='80'>
    This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
</textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
</script>
</form>
```

Anything I'm missing here? I've tried including the separate HTML file (that works) into the PHP code, dropping out of PHP and back in after the above code, etc. All to no avail.

Thanks!

Edit:
This seems to be working to load the new version in PHP... hope this helps someone in the future or maybe someone will point out a better solution? Thanks for the help!

```
$ckeditor = new CKEditor();
$ckeditor->basePath = 'lib/ckeditor-new/';
//$ckeditor->config['height'] = 100;
$ckeditor->editor('editor1');
```

Comment: is your php script in the same location as the html file? did you adjust your relative path to account for any differences? done any basic debugging, like checking your debug console for errors?

Comment: Did not do any debugging (I know right!) but I did move the html file around to include the same folder as the php as well as adjusting the path. 

However, after posting this I found a solution that is working! (See original post).

This was actually the old code used with the previous version of ckeditor but after pointing it to the new files, seems to be loading those quite nicely. Ugh! Wish their documentation would include for PHP. Thanks for the help!